# Multiline Listview Items with jQuery Mobile

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, multiline, listviewitem

I can´t figure out how to do multilined listview items in jQuery Mobile depicted in the image below (some additional infos...)

Image:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-GSNEPObTo2c/T4m9GbfAcgI/AAAAAAAABec/fot1TgehC6w/s279/Bildschirmfoto%25202012-04-14%2520um%252020.01.37.png

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot,
Jakob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `li` items use the following format:

```
<li>
    <a href="first.html">
      <h3>First line</h3>
      <p>Whatever goes on the second line</p>
    </a> </li>
```

then add the following to your CSS:

```
.ui-li-desc {white-space:normal;}​
```

As an example, see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KNLUh/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g">
  <li>
    <a href="first.html">
      <h3>First line</h3>
      <p>Whatever goes on the second line</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="second.html">
      <h3>Second line</h3>
      <p>Whatever goes on the second line</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is the standard way used in most jQuery Mobile examples. It even takes care of the ellipsis truncation on the second line.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-listview > li p {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Add this code in your own CSS file. It works!